# Stack trace not found in Output during Netbeans 7.4 debugging session

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, stack-trace

In Netbeans 7.4, I set a breakpoint at the point where my program quit working and began debugging.

[image]

The first print statement printed; second didn't.

In the debugger, execution stopped here:

[image]

Even after I selected `Continue` (`F5`) from the `Debug` pulldown, there was no stack trace in the output, so I was stumped about where the error actually occurred.

So I ran again but did NOT debug. I found a stack trace; problem easily solved.

Why didn't I get one while debugging? Is this just how it is in Netbeans when debugging?

*** EDIT ***

As it happens, the exception was that `availableLetters` was `null`. I fixed the problem via the `if` statement below, but that doesn't answer my question:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu: Window->Debugging->Call Stack then it should appear in a tab of it's own underneath your code pane.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but the Question was seven months ago and I can no longer remember the details, but my **EDIT** seems to say that was the Answer I came up with.

Comment: @DSlomer64 yes I had the same problem, found your question, then found the answer, so provided it for future travelers.